# Jquery to remove all the rows from closest table

Tags: jquery

I have multiple html tables, each with a variable number of rows.

Each row has a drop down list element.  When that element changes, I'd like to remove all the rows that are in that table.

I've tried:

```
$(document).on('change', '.classofmydropdownlist', function () {

    var self = $(this);
    var thisTable = self.closest('table')
    var rows = thisTable.children('tbody').children('tr');
    rows.each(function (element) {
        $(element).remove();
    });
    $.get('/Fetchmoreitems', { 'type': self.val() }, function (html) {        
        thisTable.append(html);
    });

}
```

However the rows don't delete (although new items called by $.get successfully append)

Comment: please include html as well

Comment: The first parameter passed in the callback of `.each(function(idx, element) {...})` is the index of the current element: http://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function

Comment: `thisTable.children('tbody').children('tr').remove()` is enough, no need of `each()`. Also for refering the object use `this`, `$(this).remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the first parameter of the `each()` handler is the *index* of the element in the matched set, not a reference to the element itself - that's the second parameter:

```
rows.each(function (i, element) { // note 'i' here
    $(element).remove(); // or just $(this).remove() if you don't want to use any params
});
```

Also note that you can simplify the logic with the use of `empty()`:

```
$(document).on('change', '.classofmydropdownlist', function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    var $tbody = self.closest('table').children('tbody').empty();

    $.get('/Fetchmoreitems', { 'type': self.val() }, function(html) {        
        $tbody.append(html);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you, such an easy fix, appreciate it!

Comment: That element is also bound to `this`, so you can just use that and forget the arguments.

Comment: @RobbieMills no problem, glad to help